# Прописная/строчная

Tags: орфография

Как писать «вооруженные силы» в приведенном случае (с прописными или строчными): «после окончания военного училища проходил службу в В/вооруженных силах в различных командных должностях»?

Answer (score 1):

В официальном названии государственной военной организации государства оба слова пишутся с прописных букв, например:  Вооруженные Силы (ВС) Российской Федерации. Но в вашем примере имеется в виду не  официальное название, а просто служба в армии, поэтому пишем: «после окончания военного училища проходил службу в вооруженных силах в различных командных должностях».